# Get device time/local time from UTC time in Titanium

Tags: ios, datetime, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm working on an Titanium application.
In which I want to take the local time.
My issue is, when I use:

```
var currentDateTime = new Date();
```

It shows the **UTC time**.

Is there anyway to get the current local time or device time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue using the `getTimezoneOffset` function.

I wrote a method which **takes the UTC time as parameter and returns the local time**

```
//Function Processes the passed UTC time and returns the current device time.
function changeUTCToLocal(utcTime)
{
    var offset = utcTime.getTimezoneOffset();
    var localTime = utcTime + offset;
    return localTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the time interval from GMT time and the offset of current local time and GMT , add these and get the real time interval from local time :

suppose timeInterval is NSInteger milliseconds time from GMT ,
use following to get offset

```
  NSInteger millisecondsFromGMT = 1000 * [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
```

Now add these two to get the real time interval

```
NSInteger realTimeInterval = timeInterval + millisecondsFromGMT ;
```

Comment: I already mentioned that I'm working on Titanium based iOS application. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that moment.js can solve this problem also